# How to restrict access to pages in next.js using firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am working on a next.js app which uses firebase. I need to use firebase auth package to restrict access to pages. The with-firebase-authentication example  doesn't show authentication for multiple pages.

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

import { firebase } from '../../firebase';
import * as routes from '../../constants/routes';

const withAuthorization = (needsAuthorization) => (Component) => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        if (!authUser && needsAuthorization) {
          Router.push(routes.SIGN_IN)
        }
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component { ...this.props } />
      );
    }
  }

  return WithAuthorization;
}

export default withAuthorization;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [React Firebase Authentication](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/) example, but it should work with `next.js` as well.

The main idea is to create a Higher Order Component, which checks if the user is authenticated and wrap all pages around that:

```
import React from 'react';

const withAuthentication = Component => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return WithAuthentication;
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

You could override the `_app.js` and only return `<Component {...pageProps} />` if the user is authenticated.

You could do something like this:

```
const withAuthorization = (needsAuthorization) => (Component) => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    state = { authenticated: null }
    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        if (!authUser && needsAuthorization) {
          Router.push(routes.SIGN_IN)
        } else {
          // authenticated
          this.setState({ authenticated: true })
        }
      });
    }

    render() {
      if (!this.state.authenticated) {
        return 'Loading...'
      }
      return (
        <Component { ...this.props } />
      );
    }
  }

  return WithAuthorization;
}
```

Best would be to handle this on the server.

Comment: I have modified the question to a solution I found but the page redirects only after the said page content is rendered..

Comment: should I add the HOC to the page component ???? i tried something like you did above  but it renders  and then redirects..

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with integrating firebase auth as well, ended up using the approach detailed in the with-iron-session example on nextjs: https://github.com/hajola/with-firebase-auth-iron-session

Answer (score 0):

Hi after some research [here](https://github.com/iaincollins/nextjs-starter/issues/12) there seems to be two ways of doing this. Either you alternate the initialization process of the page using [Custom](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app)  to include authentication there - in which case you can transfer the authentication state as prop to the next page - or you would ask for a new authentication state for each page load.