# How to let only owners authenticate through a sign in page with Firebase Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create an admin portal for an already created application. Only owners should be able to authenticate through that particular page. The rest of the accounts in the firebase authentication shouldn't be redirected. I'm using React and Firebase. What are the potential solutions to that?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication makes no distinction between where the user signs in from. No matter what place they use to sign in, they end up in the same state: as an identified user.

Your application code however *can* make a distinction based on **its** knowledge of the user. For example, if you have a list of application administrators somewhere, or have [added a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to the profile of application administrators, you can use that information in a so-called auth guard in your application's routing logic.

See some of [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+auth+reactjs+auth+guard) for more information about this, and questions like this one: [How to restrict access to pages in next.js using firebase auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522858/how-to-restrict-access-to-pages-in-next-js-using-firebase-auth).